# form and action in same page or different page

Tags: php, html

Which is better, form action in the same page or another page ?
Sample code

1. ```
    <form action="act.php">    
        html code
    </form>
   ```
2. ```
   <form action = "">
      html code
    </form>
   <?php  act.php script here ?>
   ```

Which one is better 1 Or 2, which provides more security ????

Comment: It's not about one being better or more secure. It's generally a better idea to split your code from your presentation for maintainability. Sometimes it's not an option, though, depending on the requirement you're working with.

Comment: Both methods have their (potential) pros & cons.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is more secure - both are posting data to a PHP page in the same way (you could argue that you are telling less in the second example as there is no `.php` to give away the technology - but it is trivial to tell that it is PHP without this).

If your PHP code validates the input, posting to the same page means it is easier to add the annotations to the same form for the user to correct the details.

Comment: I'm new in web technologies,      In both type the client can see the page source from the browser, In the first one they can see the name of php file name. in the second one they just see a blank space in the action and they couldn't see any php script, Isn't it?

Comment: the second one always interact with server and the first one only communicate with server after only proper validation, am i correct ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your `action` attribute says for the user. A blank value just submits to itself, and the client will assume this. Both examples will interact with the server no matter what, it's up to you to create client-side or server-side validation (or both.) Although modern browsers will recognize the `required` attribute and force user validation, you should always validate on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

**Which one is better 1 Or 2**

Depends on your design model. I'd personally separate the form to the back-end logic.

**Which provides more security**

Pretty vague. But neither - from what you've given us. You'd have to do the real security (although obfuscation can be done on client-side, and some filtering using JavaScript) on the back-end.